# prettier not correcting for printWidth for certain lines of code

Tags: javascript, prettier

There are some lines of code where Prettier (we're using 2.2.1) doesn't autocorrect for `printWidth`.

For example, if `printWidth` is reduced to 70, this line:

```
const DeckList = loadable(() => import('../components/Decks/DeckList'), {});
```

gets converted to:

```
const DeckList = loadable(
  () => import('../components/Decks/DeckList'),
  {}
);
```

But this line is never autocorrected regardless of how low I set the `printWidth` value:

```
import {openNotificationWithIcon} from 'Components/Notifications/Notification.js';
```

Is this a known issue with prettier where certain lines of code have to be manually corrected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right after I posted this question, I found [this comment on the Prettier GitHub repo](https://github.com/prettier/prettier/issues/1954#issuecomment-306067705) which indicates that it's by design that prettier prioritizes the rule of keeping import statements on a single line:

> This is actually intended. We have a special case for import and require with single elements where we keep them in a single line. You don't get much more information when they are in two lines and they look worse with a series of imports. This was done due to common request from people using prettier.